# Online free OPC server for testing and debugging

Tags: java, macos, opc

I'm will to explore OLE for Process Control protocol using java. My problem is to find an OPC server for sending/retrieving of testdata. As a OS X user I cannot find an opc-server, which I can install locally. Therefore my idea was to find an external server to retrieve some test data? Is it possible or can somebody propose better idea?

Comment: Have a look [at](http://www.opcconnect.com/freesrv.php), hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to use OPC-XML:

http://advosol.us/XMLDADemo/XML_sim/OpcXMLDaServer.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 1):

I'm new in OPC , but this is what i got so far...

Check http://www.opcconnect.com/freesrv.php

**Have tested :**

- https://www.matrikonopc.com/downloads/178/software/index.aspx

  This is good, however if you need to access to a physical drive like PLC (for example modBus to connect) , it's very difficult because of COM configurations.
- http://www.kepware.com/kepserverex/

  I'm using, however, every 2 hours the server restart. Not a problem for testing.
  modBus is very easy to configure

**For Java OPC Client programming...**

I'm still seeking the best, but so far i have

- utgard openscada
- jeasyopc

As OS X user, use virtual machine, VMware player